# Delete old influxDB data

Tags: influxdb

I have an influxDB instance with more than 4 years of data (∼ 600GB) which causes very high memory consumption (more that 100GB of RAM). I want to delete data older than a year to reduce memory usage. I wanted to use retention policy but as far as I know newly created RPs only affect newly inserted data. I decided to go with deleting old data manually like this:

```
DELETE FROM \"$measurement\" WHERE time < 'YYYY-MM-DD'
```

with $measurement looping through all measurements in the database.

Is this the correct way to do it or there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using default RP, you can change it to 1 year, which will delete the existing data.

Comment: I thought changing the default RP to a limited time period will only affect new inserted data, does it also affect already existing data?

Comment: yes, it does. I also did the same thing, I have 100GB with RP 2 years.

Answer (score 1):

In influx 2.x I use:

```bash
influx delete --start=$(date -d "today -60 days" +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S)Z --stop=$(date -d now +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S)Z --bucket MY_BUCKET_NAME
```